# Tree - это класс или интерфейс?

Tags: java, дерево

Задали на собеседовании такой вопрос. Первичный гуглинг дал ответ, что такой структуры данных в чистом нативном виде вообще нет в Java, то есть только какие-то хитрые самодельные реализации через Iterable. Подскажите пожалуйста, где правду искать?

Answer (score 4):

Tree, или как еще называют Binary Tree (бинарное дерево), отсутствует в Java, так как у него проблемы с балансировкой элементов, поэтому в Java реализовали идею основанною на [красно-черных деревьях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) с самобалансировкой.

Реализации такого механизма можно посмотреть в классах [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) и [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).